# jQuery Scrolly plugin - parallax background jumps by preceding element's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Demo: http://christianbullock.org/jstest/

I'm trying to implement a basic parallax banner on a freelance project. For this I'm using: https://github.com/Victa/scrolly

Problem though. When there's an element placed before the parallax banner, when you begin scrolling, the parallax background's position will jump by the height of the preceding element.

In this case, the red banner is 218px high. When you begin scrolling, the green background's position will jump by 218px.

**Note:** This isn't a problem if the parallax element is the first element on the page. It's also not a problem if the red banner is removed from the document flow through fixed positioning.

I'm thinking the culprit it probably this, but wouldn't know where to begin diagnosing:

```
// Fix background position
if(this.bgStart){ position = position + this.bgStart; }

if(this.options.bgParallax === true) {
  this.$element.css({backgroundPosition: '50% '+position+'px'});
} else {
  this.$element.css({top: position});
}
```

Really appreciate any pointers. Thanks! :)

Comment: can you show more of the code please

Comment: Hi. The full Js can be found here: http://christianbullock.org/jstest/jquery.scrolly.js . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Had to add:

```
data-fit="-218"
```

to account for the banner at the top :)